# My Nav Bar lines are not showing up when reducing the window size

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, navbar

I had implemented a nav bar in one of my websites, and when I tried to implement the same nav bar in another website I'm creating, the hamburger lines do not show up. I can't seem to find the problem in it. The code is in react (exactly like my old implementation) and the component's code is below:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import './Navbar.scss';

function Navbar() {
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
    const [button, setButton] = useState(true);

    const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
    const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);

    const showButton = () => {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 960) {
            setButton(false);
        } else {
            setButton(true);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        showButton();
    }, []);

    window.addEventListener('resize', showButton);

    return (
        <>
            <div className='header-container'>
                <p>Book a visit by calling us 9</p>
            </div>
            <nav className='navbar'>
                <div className='navbar-container'>
                    <Link to='/' className='navbar-logo' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                        LOGOG
                    </Link>
                    {/*Below is the hamburger for the navigation bar*/}
                    <div className='menu-icon' onClick={handleClick}>
                        <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
                    </div>
                    <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                        <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link to='/' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                                Home
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link
                                to='/about'
                                className='nav-links'
                                onClick={closeMobileMenu}
                            >
                                About us
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link
                                to='/for-employers'
                                className='nav-links'
                                onClick={closeMobileMenu}
                            >
                                Information
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                   {button && <Button buttonStyle='sides'>SIGN IN</Button>}
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

The Nav bar renders well but the hamburger doesn't show up when I reduce the window size. The CSS of the same is also below:

```
.header-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 36px;
    background: #D4ED31;
    /*transform from above colour to #F0BF4C on hover*/
    transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.navbar {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(28, 27, 27) 0%, rgb(26, 23, 23) 100%);
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.navbar-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80px;
    max-width: 1500px;
}

.navbar-logo {
    color: #fff;
    justify-self: start;
    margin-left: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.fa-typo3 {
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.nav-menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60vw;
    justify-content: end;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

.nav-item {
    height: 80px;
}

.nav-links {
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-links:hover {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.fa-bars {
    color: #fff;
}

.nav-links-mobile {
    display: none;
}

.menu-icon {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .NavbarItems {
        position: relative;
    }

    .nav-menu {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        height: 90vh;
        position: absolute;
        top: 80px;
        left: -100%;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    .nav-menu.active {
        background: #242222;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .nav-links {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2rem;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
    }

    .nav-links:hover {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #242424;
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    .navbar-logo {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        transform: translate(25%, 50%);
    }

    .menu-icon {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .fa-times {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    .nav-links-mobile {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 2rem auto;
        border-radius: 4px;
        width: 80%;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        background-color: transparent;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    }

    .nav-links-mobile:hover {
        background: #fff;
        color: #242424;
        transition: 250ms;
    }
}
```

Can anyone find the problem as it's been bugging me out.

Comment: can you share jsfiddle or something, where we can see the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks fine. Can you check if you're importing the FA modules right? For starters add the below code in index.html and see if it works.

```
    <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.1/css/all.css"
            integrity="sha384-xxzQGERXS00kBmZW/6qxqJPyxW3UR0BPsL4c8ILaIWXva5kFi7TxkIIaMiKtqV1Q"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
```

This may be the only reason you're not able to see the X and bars when reducing the window size as it's working on my end. Hope this helps!